Fast avro does not deserialize the message correctly
I use fast avro to deserialize the message in several schemes. I have n number of schemas created with pydantic avro. When I get a message I don't know exactly which schema it is serialized to, so I try to deserialize them in a loop expecting to deserialize it by the first successful one. However, sometimes fastavro deserializes the message using the wrong scheme.
def _deserialize_first(data, schemas):
    for schema in schemas:
        buffer = BytesIO(data)
        try:
            return schemaless_reader(buffer, schema)
        except Exception:
            continue
    return None

For example, I have schemas:
class FoundCityMessage(AvroBase):
    id: int
    action: str
    city_name: str

class TapMessage(AvroBase):
    id: int
    action: str
    count_of_taps: int
    timestamp: float

For a request serialized by TapMessage, the string found is always tap, and for Found action = found. If I send a request with action found and city_name = BBB the message is deserialized correctly, but if the string is longer than three characters I get action = found, but then I don't get city_name, I get count_of_taps and timestamp.
how do i make it so that the message deserializes only in the correct avro scheme?
Edit after a sentence from the comments. Now the message is not deserialized by any of the schemes
def _deserialize_first(data, schemas: list[dict]):
    for schema in schemas:
        buffer = BytesIO(data)
        buffer.seek(0)
        try:
            validate(data, schema, strict=True)
            return schemaless_reader(buffer, schema)
        except ValidationError:
            continue
    return None


First, you must define what you mean by "Correct" scheme. If it's able to deserialize the message, then it's a functional schema. Can you provide example schemas and inputs?

Hi! I've updated the question

You could try using from fastavro.validation import validate rather than a try, except block. It looks like you may be looking for the strict=True parameter  https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html

Would it help to discard the wrong scheme?

In my case there is no None in the deserialized message, it just doesn't have the field that should be there

Exactly.. Currently the fields that don't exist are just being set to None. strict=True means that all fields must exist or it doesn't match the schema.

Thank you so much! I'll give it a try

That didn't help, now it doesn't deserialize in any of the schemes

Pass data to validate, not buffer.

Still didn't help, messages stopped deserializing altogether

I'm afraid I don't know enough about fastavro to further help, and may have provided imperfect information. Sorry
